# How to use CSV HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy without knowing the class before

Tags: java, csv

I'm having a big problem. I want to map a CSV file to my entites. This should happen dynamically. I get a file and mapping of the user from the frontend. It contains the headerColumn, the class and the attribute. This will be iterated through a JSONArray. So I can't know the class because maybe the user tells that he wants to have the headerColumn "abc" as Article.articleName but in the same CSV the headerColumn "def" as Competitor.location.

My attempt:

```java
     List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

         Class<?> cls = Class.forName(pathToEntities + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get(classKey).toString());
         maps.put(cls, columnMapping);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
         Class cls = classes.get(i);
         CsvToBean<cls> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<cls>();

         columnMapping.put("LANGU", "id");
         columnMapping.put("TXTMD", "fname");
         columnMapping.put("Lname", "lname");

         HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<cls> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<cls>();
         strategy.setType(cls);
         strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);
     }
```

I hope you can follow me. For every class I've wanted to run this whole mapping process. The columnMapping Map would have been given to this class then. But the compiler can't work with this and tells me when I give the `CsvToBean` a variable instead of a class: `cls cannot be resolved to a type`

The library is OpenCSV here. **But I really don't care which CSV library to use**. I just want it to work. I would implement every single of them no matter. This now seems not fixable for me.

Comment: Hi, is there any errors now?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi the error is that this is not compileable because he forces me to tell a class and not a variable with a class. It seems like it's recommended to hardcode the class...

Comment: Do you already have created entity class (which you use in Class.forName() ) in your project?

Comment: Yes of course. I got many of them. @IshikawaYoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `instanceof` to check what entity you get from Class.forName()

```
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Simple.csv"));
        Class aClass = Class.forName("com.ishikawa.csvparser.entity.SimpleEntity");
        CsvToBean ctb = new CsvToBean();
        HashMap<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<>();

        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy headerStrategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy();

        columnMapping.put("LANGU", "name");
        headerStrategy.setType(aClass);
        headerStrategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

        ctb.setMappingStrategy(headerStrategy);
        ctb.setCsvReader(csvReader);



        List parse = ctb.parse();
        parse.stream().forEach(e->{
            if (e instanceof SimpleEntity) {
                System.out.println(((SimpleEntity)e).getName());
            }
        });
```

with simple.csv

```
LANGU
asd
asdf
```

and entity as example

```
package com.ishikawa.csvparser.entity;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SimpleEntity {

    public String name;
}
```

hope it helps you.

**upd1**
If you need to change separator and add created instance of CSVParser to CSVReader

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
        .withSeparator(';')
        .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
        .build();

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader)
        .withSkipLines(0)
        .withCSVParser(parser)
        .build();
```

Comment: At least no error in my IDE anymore. I'll try. Do I not need the annotation for name: @CsvBindByName(column = "name") ?

Comment: I think no, this is analog of
columnMapping.put("LANGU", "name");

Comment: The problem now is something what I don't understand. It tells me:  com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: The number of data fields does not match the number of headings. I've translated that myself now. What does it mean with number of dataFields? My csv contains 5 and I did columnMapping.put("header", "mappedname"); for all of them

Comment: i think you need delete @CsvBindByName from entity fields when you use dynamic mapping, and check that entity have same fields count

Comment: I deleted it. Same error. First csv header lines looks like this: /B46/S_RPAWG1;LANGU;TXTSH;TXTMD;TXTLG. Does openCSV has a problem with the ; delimiter maybe?

Comment: main problem with delimiter ; is that is not comma. You can change separator to ; by using CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build(); but by default opencsv use comma.

Comment: I've tried with a comma separated and it worked. So also you solution should work. I will accept as soon as I'm sure it works. But I can't you the CSVParser because the CsvToBean wants a reader and not a parser...

Comment: Please check upd1 in answer

Comment: It seems to work now! It's kinda horrible or strange for me to understand why a TypeScript CSV library (PapaParse) can do this without any specification but in Java everything needs to be done manually... but I'm very grateful for your help! You saved my day, really. The last thing that's not so nice is that the mapping automatically gives my primaryKey the value 0. But maybe it gets overwritten by the @GeneratedValue I don't know...